# Adjusting bootstrap classes and dive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I want to adjust Add Admin button in the front of admin lists and float left but I don't know where I am doing a mistake, code and screenshot is below.

Screen Shot:

[image]

My Code is  ( Bootstrap with cakephp2 )

```
<div id="page-content" class="col-sm-12">

        <h2><?php echo __('Admin Lists'); ?></h2>        <h2><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Admin'), array('action' => 'add'), array('class' => 'pull-right btn btn-primary')); ?></h2>




        <div class="users index">

            <div class="table-responsive">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To float the button to the left you need to use `pull-left` css class, not `pull-right`:

```
<h2><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Admin'), array('action' => 'add'), array('class' => 'pull-left btn btn-primary')); ?></h2>
```

Or remove the `pull-right` class completely as it is not necessary:

```
<h2><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Admin'), array('action' => 'add'), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?></h2>
```

Not 100% sure what you mean by saying "adjust Add Admin button in the front of admin lists", but I believe you just need to switch your heading tags around:

```
<!-- first -->
<h2><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Admin'), array('action' => 'add'), array('class' => 'pull-right btn btn-primary')); ?></h2>
<!-- second -->
<h2><?php echo __('Admin Lists'); ?></h2>
```

Comment: Its done , just replaced my code at top of the admin list line and it works with pull right, Thank you for the help